# Firebase error log with no Firebase configured

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have an Android Studio Project where I use GCM to get notifications, so I have Play Services and all GCM stuff. The problem that I'm facing is that I always get Firebase log when I receive a message even when I have no firebase configured in my project or files added to the gradle.

The GCM works fine, the problem here is that weird firebase log.

My Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.appname"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 39
        versionName "1.1"
        renderscriptTargetApi 20
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.6.0'
    // IMAGE LOADER
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.1'

    // GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
}
```

Here is what I get everytime:

```
08-22 12:18:39.981 26138-26138/com.example.appname E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement
08-22 12:18:39.985 2767-4133/? W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT pkg=com.example.appname (has extras) } U=0: not found
08-22 12:18:39.986 26138-26138/com.example.appname E/FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.
```

Comment: Hi Onelio, any reason you're not using FCM yet?

Comment: AL. Because the company want it this way

Comment: You should point out to the company that it is being strongly suggested that FCM be used. Some bugs that existed in GCM have their fixes in FCM. I think they would understand that.